# Code for Function

Tags: c, arrays, function, typedef

I am studying for a test on C an I was completing this exercise which I am not quite sure if I got the right code for it. Pseudocode is:  Show code for the function
`int determineBest(Player playerM [], int iPlayerCnt)` which is passed an array of players and a count of the players. **determineBest** returns the subscript of the player with the best shooting percentage(Highest shots made / shots attempted).
 Example:

```
Player playerM[] = { {"Lebron James", 10 ,30}, 
                     {"Tim Duncan", 17,20} ,
                     {"Kevin Durrant", 9,10}
                   };
```

For the data, `determinebest` would return subscript 2.

I am not sure what does it means by returning Subscript 2

**Code**

```
tydef struct
{ 
 char szName[30];
  int iShotMade;
  int iShotAttempt;
} Player;

int determineBest(Player playerM [], int iPlayerCnt)
{
   int i, iIndex= -1;
   double dCurrent, dBest = 0.0;

   for(i = 0; i < iPlayerCnt, i++)
   {
      if(Player[i].iShotAttempt == 0)
         {continue}

      dcurrent= (double)(PlayerM[i].iShotMade/PlayerM[i].iShotAttempt);

      if(dcurrent > dbest)
         dBest=dCurrent;

      iIndex= i;
   }

   return iIndex;
}
```

Comment: First of all indent your code. Unreadable code is the source of many problems.

Comment: "Lebron James"`has subscript 0, "Tim Duncan" has subscript 1 etc.

Comment: I formatted your code for you. Please format it yourself in future posts. If it is difficult to read and understand, you are likely to get less help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`returning Subscript 2` means that it finds the element in the array that is the best player.

```
0 --> {"Lebron James", 10 ,30}, 
1 --> {"Tim Duncan", 17,20} ,
2 --> {"Kevin Durrant", 9,10}
```

You should be calling this in the following manner

```
int best = determineBest(playerM [], iPlayerCnt);
```

Note, we can't see the `main()` of your program, so `iPlayerCnt` may actually be a different variable in `main()`, it's whatever keeps track of the size of your array.

Then you can access the info for the best player via

```
playerM[best]
```

as in

```
printf("%s is the best player\n", playerM[best].szName);
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually don't have a main for the code I just have the instructions for the function asked, but your answer clears my doubt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> determineBest() returns the subscript of the player with the best shooting percentage(Highest shots made / shots attempted)

```
Player playerM[] = { {"Lebron James", 10 ,30}, 
                     {"Tim Duncan", 17,20} ,
                     {"Kevin Durrant", 9,10}
                   };
```

> For the data, determinebest() would return subscript 2.
>
> I am not sure what does it means by returning Subscript 2

@MichaelWalz exampled about subscripts. in this case, the function `determinebest()` determines that "subscript 2" should be returned (meaning that it returns the integer value 2), because `{"Kevin Durrant", 9,10}` is

> the player with the best shooting percentage(Highest shots made /
>   shots attempted)

If that is not clear, just say so & we can explain further.

Comment: Thank you I understand now!

Comment: Then, feel free to accept this as the answer, as doing so will help others who read this question in future. Glad to have been of help :-)